# Can I withdraw unsettled funds?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-exchanges, starting-out-investing

I recently made a purchase of stock and made a good gain on it. However, i need the funds to make a purchase ASAP. Is it possible to withdraw the money from my cash-only brokerage account into my checking account without violating and settlement, T+3 regulations?

Comment: Did you sell the stock? Unless you have other funds in your trading account you cannot withdraw any funds until the funds are settled and available in your account.

Comment: Yeah i sold the stock

Answer (score 3):

Yes, via a margin account, one can trade or transfer on unsettled funds.

These are tight regulations that begin with the Federal Reserve, extend to FINRA, and downward.

In a cash account, this is not possible.

Since speed is a necessity, a margin account can actually be approved nearly instantly.